# Bokeh plotting error : Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, bokeh

The code below contains two functions that scrape "contract data" and "prices" from a website. Inside the functions the data is cleaned and the value is passed to update() function which extracts data every ten seconds.
When I just run the Bokeh server print(source.data) function prints the first ten refreshed values at regular intervals.
However, when I want to plot the data on vbar chart it gives the subject error.

## Code

```
 from urllib.request import urlopen
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 from bokeh.models import Range1d, LinearAxis, DataRange1d
 import time
 from datetime import datetime
 from bokeh.io import curdoc
 from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DatetimeTickFormatter, ColorBar, LabelSet
 from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
 from math import radians
 import pandas as pd
 from pymongo import MongoClient
 from bokeh.models import HoverTool
 from bokeh.models import SingleIntervalTicker, LinearAxis
 from bokeh.layouts import gridplot, row
 from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput
 from flask import Flask, render_template, request
 from bokeh.resources import CDN
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import pandas as pd
 import requests
 import numpy as np
 from math import pi
 from bokeh.models import NumeralTickFormatter
 from bokeh.models.glyphs import Line as Line_glyph

 p = figure()


def extract_contract():
        Contracts =[]
        res = requests.get('https://shared.websol.barchart.com/quotes/quote.php? 
        page=quote&sym=ng&x=13&y=8&domain=if&display_ice=1&enabled_ice_exchanges=&tz=0&ed=0')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
        soup.prettify()
        data_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[2:]
        for td in data_rows:
           Contract = td.findAll('td')[0].text
           Contracts.append(Contract)
           df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Contracts' : Contracts})
           month_mapper = {
            'Cash':'Current',
            'Jan': 'January',
            'Feb': 'February',
            'Mar': 'March',
            'Apr': 'April',
            'May': 'May', 
            'Jun': 'June',
            'Jul': 'July',
            'Aug': 'August',
            'Sep': 'September',
            'Oct': 'October',
            'Nov': 'November',
            'Dec': 'December',
                   }
        def clean_month_string(s):
                s = s.replace('\\', '')
                month, year, code = s.split(' ')
                month = month_mapper[month]
                year = year.replace("'", "")
                return ' '.join([month, year])
        df2 = df2.drop(0).reset_index(drop=True)
        df2['Contracts'] = df2['Contracts'].astype(str)
        df2['Contracts'] = df2['Contracts'].apply(clean_month_string)
    return df2.iloc[:10]

def extract_price():
      Prices =[]
      res = requests.get('https://shared.websol.barchart.com/quotes/quote.php? 
      page=quote&sym=ng&x=13&y=8&domain=if&display_ice=1&enabled_ice_exchanges=&tz=0&ed=0')
      soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
      soup.prettify()
      data_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[2:]
      for td in data_rows:
         Price = td.findAll('td')[1].text
         Prices.append(Price)
         df3 = pd.DataFrame(Prices)
         df3.replace('s','',regex=True,inplace=True)
         df3 = df3.astype(float)
         return df3.iloc[:10]

         source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[],y=[]))

         def update():    
         new_data = dict(x= [extract_contract()], y = [extract_price()])
         source.stream(new_data,rollover=200000000)
         print(source.data)

p = figure(x_range= 'x', plot_height=1000, title="Monthly Natural Gas 
Cost impact based on realtime futures contract",
toolbar_location=None, plot_width=1600)
p.vbar(x='x', top='y', width=0.2)

p.yaxis.formatter=NumeralTickFormatter(format="$00")

curdoc().add_root(p)
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update,1000)
```

## Output of extract_contract()

```
Contracts
0   March 20
1   April 20
2   May 20
3   June 20
4   July 20
5   August 20
6   September 20
7   October 20
8   November 20
9   December 20
```

## Output of extract_price()

```
0   1.871
1   1.867
2   1.894
3   1.943
4   2.001
5   2.068
6   2.099
7   2.098
8   2.133
9   2.238
```

Comment: Since plotting the `vbar` is what prompts the error, you need to actually provide that cod, since that is probably where the error lies.

Comment: @bigreddot just added it

Comment: Your code, as written, does not make sense. You aren't passing any `source` argument to `vbar` for one, so it has not data at all to draw from. Also you should almost always create one `ColumnDataSource` once, up front, and then update the `.data` property of the source later. All the examples in the docs are repo demonstrate this pattern. You should study the simplest example, and emulate itst structure: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders.py There is too much missing above (plus too much extra irrelevant things) for me to say anything else.